# How to make VisualStudio intellisense work in html properties of strongly typed view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, intellisense

If I put something like:

```
<%=Model.Project.Id %>
```

in the body of a strongly typed view, I get full intellisense for my model.

However, if I put:

```
<a href="/Projects/Edit/<%=Model.Project.Id %>">
```

With the script being written within an html property (in this case the href="" property), the intellisense doesn't work.

I imagine this is a limitation of VisualStudio, but it seems this is a very common task and should be able to work. Is there a fix for this? Does my version of VisualStudio have a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense is probably not active in text blocks (between double quotes), which is completely normal.

However i never used Visual Studio to develop asp.net application so i can't tell you how fix it but i have a idea.

[Reshaper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/) is a powerful tools for .net applications. It supports asp.net and might do what you need. You should try it !

Comment: Will check out Reshaper and report back, ideally VS would provide this natively.

Comment: I've marked this reply as answer, since it appears to be the reality. If someone comes up with a solution, I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you force IntelliSense to show up? I think the standard shortcut ist CTRL + Space ?

Comment: Just tried this, it does force intellisense, but not in the expected context, i.e. it shows a list of files to populate the href property, not the model property, e.g. Model.Project.[Intellisense here].

I think the problem is probably that VS isn't geared towards the kind of behavior common for asp.net MVC.